Error when Importing pandas in embedded python in C++
I'm working with Python 3.10 64-bit，win10，vs2013
I run the python script alone and there are no errors and it also imports the pandas package properly.However, when calling python scripts in c++ (scripts that include imported pandas) it gives an error.
In the following example, loading pandas in test63.py gives an error.
testproject.cpp
#include "testproject.h"
#include <QDebug>

testproject::testproject(QObject *parent)
: QObject(parent)
{
    Py_SetPythonHome(L"D:/anaconda3/envs/newenvs/");
    Py_Initialize();

    if (Py_IsInitialized() == 0){
        qDebug() << "fal to initialize Python\n";
        return;
    }
    qDebug() << "server start\n";

    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('D:/pycode')");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import pandas as pd");


    PyObject* comModule = PyImport_ImportModule("test63");
    if (!comModule)
    {
        PyErr_Print();
        qDebug() << "Python get module failed: test63.py.";
        Py_DECREF(comModule);
        return ;
    }
    PyObject* offline_test = PyObject_GetAttrString(comModule, "caljiandan");
    PyObject* args = PyTuple_New(2);
    PyTuple_SetItem(args, 0, Py_BuildValue("i", 2));
    PyTuple_SetItem(args, 1, Py_BuildValue("i", 3));

    PyObject* pRet_Ot = PyObject_CallObject(offline_test, args);
    int SRresult = -1;
    if (pRet_Ot)
    {
        PyArg_Parse(pRet_Ot, "i", &SRresult);
        qDebug() << "succeed:" << SRresult;
    }
    Py_DECREF(comModule); Py_DECREF(offline_test); Py_DECREF(args); Py_DECREF(pRet_Ot);
    qDebug() << "end";
}

testproject::~testproject()
{
    Py_Finalize();
}


testproject.h
#ifndef TESTPROJECT_H
#define TESTPROJECT_H

#include <QObject>
#pragma push_macro("slots")
#undef slots
#include "Python.h"
#pragma pop_macro("slots")

class testproject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    testproject(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~testproject();

private:

};

#endif // TESTPROJECT_H

main.cpp
#include "testproject.h"
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    testproject w;

    return a.exec();
}

The error message is as follows：
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\newenvs\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\newenvs\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pandas.core.dtypes.dtypes import (
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\newenvs\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\dtypes.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pandas.errors import PerformanceWarning
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\newenvs\lib\site-packages\pandas\errors\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\newenvs\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes: Can't find specified module.

Solutions that have been tried：
1.ffi.dll，ffi-7.dll，ffi-8.These dll files are not missing.
2.When calling python 3.7, import pandas does not report an error. But I need to use python 3.8 or higher (3.8 or higher, pandas gives me an error).

welcome to SO, your post lacks minimal details. Recommend you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example then edit your submission such that folks can respond

For those wondering, the message states "the specified module cannot be found".

Perhaps ctypes' __init__ is trying to dynamically load a native library from a fixed list of paths which SetPythonHome doesn't affect and can't find it there.

Run you program alongside procmon.exe to see which DLL it is loading.

I put the fi.dll, ffi-7.dll, ffi-8.dll files into the C:\Windows\System32 directory and it solved the problem!

That is a terrible solution. You should figure out why your library search path is broken instead.
